# log in fails when mount point changes

Tags: centos7, cifs, fstab

I am mounting a windows 10 share on a Centos 7 machine via */etc/fstab* like so:

```
//10.11.11.7/shared_folder   /path/to/mount_point  cifs  user,rw,suid,uid=0,gid=1111,username=win_user,password=win_user,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0   0 0
```

When I log in with a user who is part of permission group 1111 the log in process is interrupted and I am kicked back to the login screen. If I log in with a user outside of the 1111 group the log in succeeds (with the mounted folder not being accessible of course).

If I create a new folder called **"mount_point_new"** and adjust the fstab accordingly, all works well, i.e.:

```
//10.11.11.7/shared_folder   /path/to/mount_point_new  cifs  user,rw,suid,uid=0,gid=1111,username=win_user,password=win_user,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0777,vers=3.0   0 0
```

Both **"mount_point"** and **"mount_point_new"** have the same permissions pre-mount.
I would really like to use the original name (**"mount_point"**) as the path is used in some configs.
I am not a professional admin but a one-man-band home office setup, so would really like to understand the issue and fix it rather than avoid it by using a new mount point name.

Here is a snippet from */var/log/messages* right after a failed login:

```
Jun 29 17:20:17 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service'
Jun 29 17:20:17 spiff systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Jun 29 17:20:17 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jun 29 17:20:17 spiff systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Jun 29 17:20:36 spiff systemd-logind: New session 3 of user frank.
Jun 29 17:20:36 spiff systemd: Started Session 3 of user frank.
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gnome-session-binary[2825]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff journal: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff journal: Cannot open display: 
Jun 29 17:20:38 spiff gdm: Failed to remove greeter program access to the display. Trying to proceed.
Jun 29 17:20:39 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408039.137374]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO: Starting imsettings-daemon...
Jun 29 17:20:39 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408039.139154]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO:   [HOME=/mnt/home/frank/.config/imsettings]
Jun 29 17:20:39 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408039.140495]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO:   [XINPUTRCDIR=/etc/X11/xinit/]
Jun 29 17:20:39 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408039.141764]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO:   [XINPUTDIR=/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/]
Jun 29 17:20:39 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408039.143115]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO:   [MODULEDIR=/usr/lib64/imsettings]
Jun 29 17:20:39 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408039.144508]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO:   [MODULES=gsettings, qt]
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408045.764493]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO: Release the ownership of com.redhat.imsettings
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: Exiting...
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408045.767041]: GLib-GIO[6377]: CRITICAL **: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408045.768427]: GLib-GIO[6377]: CRITICAL **: Error while sending AddMatch() message: The connection is closed
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408045.769742]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO: Unloading imesttings module: qt
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408045.770996]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO: Unloading imesttings module: gsettings
Jun 29 17:20:45 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408045.772340]: IMSettings-Daemon[6377]: INFO: imsettings-daemon is shut down.
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff systemd-logind: New session c2 of user gdm.
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff systemd: Started Session c2 of user gdm.
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff org.a11y.Bus: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff org.a11y.Bus: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff org.a11y.atspi.Registry: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff gnome-session: generating cookie with syscall
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file orca-autostart.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Could not parse desktop file orca-autostart.desktop or it references a not found TryExec binary
Jun 29 17:20:47 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating service name='org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd' (using servicehelper)
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.fedoraproject.Setroubleshootd'
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service'
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff systemd: Starting Locale Service...
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff systemd: Started Locale Service.
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff setroubleshoot: Exception during AVC analysis: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
Jun 29 17:20:48 spiff setroubleshoot: Exception during AVC analysis: must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff journal: Failed to connect to avahi service: Daemon not running
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Started Location Lookup Service.
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff journal: No permission to trigger offline updates: Polkit.Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.packagekit.trigger-offline-update is not registered
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff spice-vdagent[6825]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff gnome-session-binary: Entering running state
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff spice-streaming-agent[6827]: Failed to open the streaming device "/dev/virtio-ports/org.spice-space.stream.0": 2 - No such file or directory
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff journal: Some code accessed the property 'AuthList' on the module 'authList'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.realmd' unit='realmd.service'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Starting Realm and Domain Configuration...
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.realmd'
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff systemd: Started Realm and Domain Configuration.
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff journal: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff org.gnome.Shell.desktop: Window manager warning: "XF86RFKill" is not a valid accelerator
Jun 29 17:20:49 spiff journal: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/layout.js 29]: reference to undefined property "MetaWindowX11"
Jun 29 17:20:50 spiff journal: Screen lock is locked down, not locking
Jun 29 17:20:52 spiff journal: driver/gl/cogl-framebuffer-gl.c:1558: GL error (1282): Invalid operation
Jun 29 17:21:15 spiff systemd-logind: Removed session 3.
```

Here is a snippet from */var/log/messages* after a successful log in:

```
Jun 29 17:22:09 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service'
Jun 29 17:22:09 spiff systemd: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Jun 29 17:22:09 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jun 29 17:22:09 spiff systemd: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Jun 29 17:22:11 spiff systemd-logind: New session 4 of user frank.
Jun 29 17:22:11 spiff systemd: Started Session 4 of user frank.
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session: gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard.desktop' killed by signal 15
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gnome-session-binary[6605]: WARNING: Lost name on bus: org.gnome.SessionManager
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff journal: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff journal: GChildWatchSource: Exit status of a child process was requested but ECHILD was received by waitpid(). See the documentation of g_child_watch_source_new() for possible causes.
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff journal: Cannot open display: 
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff gdm: Failed to remove greeter program access to the display. Trying to proceed.
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff systemd-logind: Removed session c2.
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408134.779897]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO: Starting imsettings-daemon...
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408134.781320]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   [HOME=/mnt/home/frank/.config/imsettings]
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408134.782272]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   [XINPUTRCDIR=/etc/X11/xinit/]
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408134.783187]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   [XINPUTDIR=/etc/X11/xinit/xinput.d/]
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408134.784091]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   [MODULEDIR=/usr/lib64/imsettings]
Jun 29 17:22:14 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408134.784952]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   [MODULES=gsettings, qt]
Jun 29 17:22:17 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Activating service name='org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper' (using servicehelper)
Jun 29 17:22:18 spiff org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper: no kernel backlight interface found
Jun 29 17:22:18 spiff dbus[1239]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper'
Jun 29 17:22:23 spiff NetworkManager[1478]: <info>  [1593408143.1494] agent-manager: req[0x55c9e6008650, :1.112/org.kde.networkmanagement/1001]: agent registered
Jun 29 17:22:27 spiff rtkit-daemon[1354]: Successfully made thread 8504 of process 8504 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1001' high priority at nice level -11.
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.095736]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: WARNING **: Child process exited with code 1
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.100009]: IMSettings-Qt backend[8077]: WARNING **: Unable to obtain the DefaultInputMethod: Key file does not have group ?Qt?
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff spice-vdagent[8524]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff spice-streaming-agent[8523]: Failed to open the streaming device "/dev/virtio-ports/org.spice-space.stream.0": 2 - No such file or directory
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.263348]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO: Attempting to switch IM to none [lang=en_NZ.UTF-8, update=false]
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.321061]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: WARNING **: Child process exited with code 1
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.322752]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   no need to invoke any auxiliary process for none
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.324006]: IMSettings-Daemon[8077]: INFO:   no need to invoke any main process for none
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff org.a11y.Bus: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff rtkit-daemon[1354]: Successfully made thread 8578 of process 8504 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff org.a11y.Bus: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff org.a11y.atspi.Registry: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff rtkit-daemon[1354]: Successfully made thread 8591 of process 8504 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1001' RT at priority 5.
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.372124]: IMSettings-Qt backend[8077]: INFO: Setting up xim as Qt immodule
Jun 29 17:22:28 spiff com.redhat.imsettings: [ 1593408148.374189]: IMSettings-GSettings backend[8077]: INFO: Setting up gtk-im-context-simple:xim as gtk+ immodule
```

Comment: What is the actual path?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - the path to the mount points? It's /ohufx/pipeline/dlRepo and /ohufx/pipeline/dlRepo_new

Comment: I suspect you've got some sort of SELinux problem. Check the contexts on each mount point.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton - here is the context for the mount point in question (this only happens with the cifs mount point, all nfs ones work just fine):

`[frankadmin@spiff ~]$ ls -dZ /ohufx/pipeline/dlRepo`

`drwxrwxrwx. root ohufx system_u:object_r:cifs_t:s0      /ohufx/pipeline/dlRepo`

Comment: @MichaelHampton - I just disabled SELinux altogether but it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the */path/to/mount_point/some/subfolder* was part of my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (for good reason), and the files in that location interfere with the login process. I have removed the path from LD_LIBRARY_PATH and can now successfully log in.